# scala spark UDF filter array of struct

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe with schema

```
root
 |-- x: Long (nullable = false)
 |-- y: Long (nullable = false)
 |-- features: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- score: double (nullable = true)
```

For example, I have data

```
+--------------------+--------------------+------------------------------------------+
|                x   |              y     |       features                           |
+--------------------+--------------------+------------------------------------------+
|10                  |          9         |[["f1", 5.9], ["ft2", 6.0], ["ft3", 10.9]]|
|11                  |          0         |[["f4", 0.9], ["ft1", 4.0], ["ft2", 0.9] ]|
|20                  |          9         |[["f5", 5.9], ["ft2", 6.4], ["ft3", 1.9] ]|
|18                  |          8         |[["f1", 5.9], ["ft4", 8.1], ["ft2", 18.9]]|
+--------------------+--------------------+------------------------------------------+
```

I would like to filter the features with a particular prefix, say "ft", so eventually I want the result:

```
+--------------------+--------------------+-----------------------------+
|                x   |              y     |       features              |
+--------------------+--------------------+-----------------------------+
|10                  |          9         |[["ft2", 6.0], ["ft3", 10.9]]|
|11                  |          0         |[["ft1", 4.0], ["ft2", 0.9] ]|
|20                  |          9         |[["ft2", 6.4], ["ft3", 1.9] ]|
|18                  |          8         |[["ft4", 8.1], ["ft2", 18.9]]|
+--------------------+--------------------+-----------------------------+
```

I'm not using Spark 2.4+ so I cannot use the solution provided here: [Spark (Scala) filter array of structs without explode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54954732/spark-scala-filter-array-of-structs-without-explode)

I tried to use UDF, but still does not work. Here are my attempts. I define a UDF:

```
def filterFeature: UserDefinedFunction = 
udf((features: Seq[Row]) =>
    features.filter{
        x.getString(0).startsWith("ft")
    }
)
```

But if I apply this UDF

```
df.withColumn("filtered", filterFeature($"features"))
```

I get the error `Schema for type org.apache.spark.sql.Row is not supported`. I found that I can't return `Row` from UDF. Then I tried

```
def filterFeature: UserDefinedFunction = 
udf((features: Seq[Row]) =>
    features.filter{
        x.getString(0).startsWith("ft")
    }, (StringType, DoubleType)
)
```

I then got an error:

```
 error: type mismatch;
 found   : (org.apache.spark.sql.types.StringType.type, org.apache.spark.sql.types.DoubleType.type)
 required: org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataType
              }, (StringType, DoubleType)
                 ^
```

I also tried a case class as suggested by some answers:

```
case class FilteredFeature(featureName: String, featureScore: Double)
def filterFeature: UserDefinedFunction = 
udf((features: Seq[Row]) =>
    features.filter{
        x.getString(0).startsWith("ft")
    }, FilteredFeature
)
```

But I got:

```
 error: type mismatch;
 found   : FilteredFeature.type
 required: org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataType
              }, FilteredFeature
                 ^
```

I tried:

```
case class FilteredFeature(featureName: String, featureScore: Double)
def filterFeature: UserDefinedFunction = 
udf((features: Seq[Row]) =>
    features.filter{
        x.getString(0).startsWith("ft")
    }, Seq[FilteredFeature]
)
```

I got:

```
<console>:192: error: missing argument list for method apply in class GenericCompanion
Unapplied methods are only converted to functions when a function type is expected.
You can make this conversion explicit by writing `apply _` or `apply(_)` instead of `apply`.
              }, Seq[FilteredFeature]
                    ^
```

I tried:

```
case class FilteredFeature(featureName: String, featureScore: Double)
def filterFeature: UserDefinedFunction = 
udf((features: Seq[Row]) =>
    features.filter{
        x.getString(0).startsWith("ft")
    }, Seq[FilteredFeature](_)
)
```

I got:

```
<console>:201: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Seq[FilteredFeature]
 required: FilteredFeature
              }, Seq[FilteredFeature](_)
                          ^
```

What should I do in this case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two Options :

a) provide a schema to the UDF, this let's you return `Seq[Row]`

b) convert `Seq[Row]` to a `Seq` of `Tuple2` or a case class, then you don't need to provide a schema (but struct field names are lost if you use Tuples!)

I would prefer option a) for your case (works well for structs with many fields):

```
val schema = df.schema("features").dataType

val filterFeature = udf((features:Seq[Row]) => features.filter(_.getAs[String]("name").startsWith("ft")),schema)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def filterFeature: UserDefinedFunction =
    udf((features: Row) => {
      features.getAs[Array[Array[Any]]]("features").filter(in => in(0).asInstanceOf[String].startsWith("ft"))
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using Spark 2.4 then, this should work in your case

```
case class FilteredFeature(featureName: String, featureScore: Double)

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._  
def filterFeature: UserDefinedFunction = udf((feature: Seq[Row]) => {
  feature.filter(x => {
    x.getString(0).startsWith("ft")
  }).map(r => FilteredFeature(r.getString(0), r.getDouble(1)))
})

df.select($"x", $"y", filterFeature($"feature") as "filter").show(false)
```

Output:

```
+---+---+-----------------------+
|x  |y  |filter                 |
+---+---+-----------------------+
|10 |9  |[[ft2,6.0], [ft3,10.9]]|
|11 |0  |[[ft1,4.0], [ft2,0.9]] |
|20 |9  |[[ft2,6.4], [ft3,1.9]] |
|18 |8  |[[ft4,8.1], [ft2,18.9]]|
+---+---+-----------------------+
```

Comment: But the schema of feature differs in your case after filtering (struct names should be name and score)